# Can not remove apt repository for java8

Tags: package-management, java, repository

I get the following error in apt update.

```
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.5 kB]                                                                                                                                  
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease                                                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
Hit:6 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                         
Reading package lists... Done                             
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried the following command to remove the repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
```

But still get the same error whenever run the apt update command. I checked the apt source and packages folders. There is nothing related to this package. Then where is this repository is referring to?

Comment: I changed the comment into an answer for you.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://askubuntu.com/a/1078746/231142 to add the GPG Key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EEA14886
```

then run

```
 sudo apt update
```

As far as turning off the repository, go to your *Settings -> Software & Updates* then click on the Other Software tab and unselect it from there.