# `sudo apt update` returns unverified and unsigned signatures due to unavailable public keys? This stemmed from wanting to reinstall wine

Tags: wine, ppa, repository

I have a hard drive which recently died, instead of paying for a new copy of Windows I went with an Ubuntu distribution.

I've been trying to run a couple different .exe files through WINE, which hasn't been working. I figured I could try a fresh reinstall of wine and ran through these steps as proposed by an article on PCsuggest posted in 2018:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine wine-*     
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge     
rm -rf ~/.wine/     
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/wine*
```

I then ran through the steps laid out to install Wine from the WineHQ site for Ubuntu 18.04. Which went well up until the

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

line, which didn't seem to work. Nevertheless, I'm pig-headed enough to keep moving forwards, so then I tried `sudo apt update`, which definitely didn't work. That command returned this:

```
Ign:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease  
Hit:2 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease                                                                          
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                           
Hit:5 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
Hit:7 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
Hit:8 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                 
Hit:9 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                
Ign:12 https://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                       
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpad.net/diesch/testing/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Ign:14 https://ppa.launchpad.net/falk-t-j/qtsixa/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
Get:4 https://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.4 kB]  
Err:4 https://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3BDAAC08614C4B38  
Get:11 https://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.7 kB]  
Err:11 https://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444  
Err:15 https://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]  
Err:16 https://ppa.launchpad.net/falk-t-j/qtsixa/ubuntu bionic Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]  
Reading package lists... Done  
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3BDAAC08614C4B38  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic  
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 83FBA1751378B444  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/falk-t-j/qtsixa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I should mention, earlier the problem was a broken line in the `sources.list` file related to WINE. Which I fixed by realizing that (I think?) I had a sources.list file for Ubuntu 16.04, which is the version I installed initially onto my laptop from a flashdrive before updating to 18.04. So I moseyed on over to https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ and downloaded a sources.list file for 18.04 and replaced the old one. I have both files backed up as text files on my desktop so if I need to put that 16.04 file back in, I think I can do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also read the formatting guide and format the console output as code, rather than plaintext, which you have to manually edit to not have too many links...

Comment: neat trick! I suppose I should have read that before making my post, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Your Windows installation key is lodged in your firmware on the motherboard if Windows was preinstalled on your PC, so if you reinstall your version of Windows, it should find the key for you. Not that Ubuntu isn't better....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) and [error while trying to sudo apt-get update GPG, no sign repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078744/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error while trying to sudo apt-get update GPG, no sign repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078744/error-while-trying-to-sudo-apt-get-update-gpg-no-sign-repository)