# Wine wont install. Seems like Ubuntu issue

Tags: xubuntu, wine

I am trying to install Wine, the latest one but I am encountering the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried switching with it around in settings, trying with the repository removed, adding the ppa key, and nothing seems to work.

The `allow --allow-unauthenticated` command doesn't work. I have tried Wine from the Ubuntu store but it's outdated and my programs won't work with it.

I am currently running Xubuntu.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release of Ubuntu/Xubuntu - is it a release supported by that PPA?   PPA's are 3rd party, so it's up to you to check they support your release & you trust the creators before adding to your system.  (*I had a quick look at that PPA; it doesn't cover my release of Lubuntu/Xubuntu - but I don't know you release so you'll have to check yourself*)

Comment: its the lts 18.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error while trying to sudo apt-get update GPG, no sign repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078744/error-while-trying-to-sudo-apt-get-update-gpg-no-sign-repository)

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```

and

`sudo apt-key add winehq.key`

[source](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

Comment: It would be useful if you added an explanation of why winehq.key is required and if this is sufficient to allow the user to complete the installation of Wine.

Comment: Nope still wont work Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                     
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                     
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                   
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository c

Comment: really ppa and winehq.org? Remove the ppa ist does not provide packages for bionic. http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/